# Fail to send mail using SMTP in C# Application

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am working on one project where I want to send mail using smtp.

I have tried below code but it is giving me error as **Failed in Sending Mail**

```
try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("From@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com", "Testing Mail", "Testing mail recv");

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myPage@gmail.com", "123@123");
client.Send(message); 
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
  MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
}
```

In place of `client.Host = "smtp.googlemail.com";` 
I have Tried some other code as `client.Host = "smtp.google.com";` and `client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";`.
also have tried with different Port No as `25` and `587`.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: We can haz exception pl0x?

Comment: can you show what error is coming

Comment: That code works fine for me.  Just check your username and password.

Comment: FYI: You may need to be aware of the google two-step authentication, that might block the access when using your "default" password.

Comment: have you enabled pop and imap in your gmail account?